# 'For' loop not executing for each value in an array containing multiple arrays

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.7

I'm very new to coding and trying to write a data processing program. Part of this program requires me to unpack multiple data files each with multiple columns, and store all these columns in an array. A 'for' loop should then execute a basic calculation on each value. I'm not sure why it doesn't work. It seems to only evaluate the loop for each value in the first array.

```
data_array1 = np.loadtxt("hst_gal1_cepheids.dat", dtype = "float", usecols = (1,2,3))
data_array2 = np.loadtxt("hst_gal2_cepheids.dat", dtype = "float", usecols = (1,2,3))
data_array3 = np.loadtxt("hst_gal3_cepheids.dat", dtype = "float", usecols = (1,2,3))
data_array4 = np.loadtxt("hst_gal4_cepheids.dat", dtype = "float", usecols = (1,2,3))
data_array5 = np.loadtxt("hst_gal5_cepheids.dat", dtype = "float", usecols = (1,2,3))
data_array6 = np.loadtxt("hst_gal6_cepheids.dat", dtype = "float", usecols = (1,2,3))
data_array7 = np.loadtxt("hst_gal7_cepheids.dat", dtype = "float", usecols = (1,2,3))
data_array8 = np.loadtxt("hst_gal8_cepheids.dat", dtype = "float", usecols = (1,2,3))

logP_days = np.array([data_array1[1], data_array2[1], data_array3[1], data_array4[1], data_array5[1] , data_array6[1] , data_array7[1], data_array8[1]])

m_V1 = np.array([data_array1[2], data_array2[2], data_array3[2], data_array4[2], data_array5[2] , data_array6[2] , data_array7[2], data_array8[2]])

m_I1 = np.array([data_array1[3], data_array2[3], data_array3[3], data_array4[3], data_array5[3] , data_array6[3] , data_array7[3], data_array8[3]])

data_array9 = np.loadtxt("galaxy_data.dat", dtype= "float", usecols = (1,2))
recessional_velocity = data_array9[1]
V_band_extinction = data_array9[2]

absV = []
absI = []

for i in logP_days:
        abs_M_V = AlphaV*i + BetaV
        absV_new = np.append(absV, abs_M_V)

for i in logP_days:
        abs_M_I = AlphaI*i + BetaI
        absI_new = np.append(absI, abs_M_I)
```

Comment: probably a misunderstanding :

        data_array1[1] 

is the index 1 row (indexes start at 0) of the data loaded from "hst_gal1_cepheids.dat". 

        data_array1[ : , 0 ] 

would be an array of the first element from each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to collect values in a list, and do one array construction at the end.  Try this:

```
absV = []
for i in logP_days:
        abs_M_V = AlphaV*i + BetaV
        absV.append(abs_M_V)
absV_new = np.array(absV)
```

List append is faster, and easier to get right.

Often there are ways of constructing the array without iterating.  Just a quick look at that that loop suggests:

```
AlphaV*np.arange(logP_days) + BetaV
```

Answer (score 0):

The `numpy.append` function that you're calling in your `for` loops doesn't modify its first argument in place (unlike `list.append`). It returns a new array with the concatenation done.

Your loop code is saving the output as `absV_new` (and `asbI_new` in the second loop), but that variable gets overwritten each time the loop repeats. Thus you'll only ever see the result of the last row of data having been appended to the always empty initial list.

It's not entirely clear to me what you expect to happen. Perhaps you want to stick with regular Python lists and use `absV.append(abs_M_V)`? Or maybe you should figure out the dimensions of your `AlphaX` and `BetaX` variables correctly and just use numpy broadcasting over the whole array of data, rather than using a Python loop (e.g. something related to `AlphaV * logP_days + BetaV`)?

Comment: All I want is for the 'for' loop to execute on each value in the logP_days array, and store all these new values in a list. Currently, when I try to print absV_new, it returns:

Out[9]: array([ -4.30240635, 271.09034583, 261.90167015]

which i assume is only the new values for the first 3 values in the original array.

Comment: That output is the *last* result from the loop. It overwrote the previous ones (just like all but the first overwrote the one before them). If you don't mind a list, take my first suggestion in my answer and replace `absV_new = np.append(absV, abs_M_V)` with `absV.append(abs_M_V)`. The results will be in the `absV` list. My other suggestion might also work, depending on what your `AlphaV` and `Beta` variables contain (and the dimensions of the other arrays, maybe).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that if you instead try:

```
ogP_days = np.array([data_array1[:,0], data_array2[:,0], data_array3[:,0], data_array4[:,0], data_array5[:,0] , data_array6[:,0] , data_array7[:,0], data_array8[:,0]])

m_V1 = np.array([data_array1[:,1], data_array2[:,1], data_array3[:,1], data_array4[:,1], data_array5[:,1] , data_array6[:,1] , data_array7[:,1], data_array8[:,1]])


m_I1 = np.array([data_array1[:,1], data_array2[:,1], data_array3[:,1], data_array4[:,1], data_array5[:,1] , data_array6[:,1] , data_array7[:,1], data_array8[:,1]])
```

and change usecols = (1,2,3) to usecols = (0,1,2) you will get better results.

I am doing two things. Slice the array [:,0] gives you the first element of each row. Also indexes start at 0.